# Angular Material Datepicker Popup positioned wrong

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, datepicker, angular-material-datetimepicker

First of all, this material datepicker is based on: https://stackblitz.com/angular/qmnrlgabjly?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-views-selection-example.ts

I have copied all the code i need from: https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview
however the popup for choosing year and date is always positioned wrong (see picture under):

[image]

I have the exact same code as the example, and my scss-file looks like this:

```
@import "../../../shared/styles/bootstrap/_variables.scss";
@import "../../../shared/styles/bootstrap/_mixins";
@import "../../../shared/styles/app/variables.scss";
@import '~@swimlane/ngx-datatable/index.css';
@import '~@swimlane/ngx-datatable/themes/bootstrap.css';
@import '~@swimlane/ngx-datatable/themes/dark.scss';
@import '~@swimlane/ngx-datatable/themes/material.scss';
@import '~@swimlane/ngx-datatable/assets/icons.css';
@import "~@angular/cdk/overlay-prebuilt.css";
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";

.home-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: map-get($container-max-widths, "lg");

    .home-logo {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;

        img {
            width: 240px;
        }
    }

    .home-text {
        text-align: center;

        @include media-breakpoint-up(lg) {
            text-align: left;
        }
    }

    .home-text-big {
        font-size: 3.9375rem;
    }


    
}
:host ::ng-deep .datatable-row-odd {
    background-color: #eee;
}


:host ::ng-deep .datatable-header {
    background-color: #f05050;
    padding: 0.5rem 0 0 0.5rem;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}

:host ::ng-deep .datatable-body-cell {
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0.5rem 0 0.5rem 0;
}

ol {
    font-size: 2.25rem;
}

#manualInput p {
    font-size: 1rem;
}

#allContent {
   display: none;
}

#ptags {
    font-size: 1rem;
}

ul{
    list-style: circle;
    padding: 0;
}

.secondLevel {
   font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.container {
    max-width: none;
}

input {
    width: 100%;
}

button {
    margin-bottom: 1rem !important;
    width: 7rem;
}

hr {
    margin-top: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 3px solid #dc3545;
}

.example-month-picker .mat-calendar-period-button {
    pointer-events: none;
}

.example-month-picker .mat-calendar-arrow {
    display: none;
}

::ng-deep .mat-form-field-underline {
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: -999;
    display: block;
}
```

And HTML:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="dp" [formControl]="date">
                    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dp"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                    <mat-datepicker #dp [touchUi]="true" disabled="false"
                                    startView="multi-year"
                                    (yearSelected)="chosenYearHandler($event)"
                                    (monthSelected)="chosenMonthHandler($event, dp)"
                                    panelClass="example-month-picker">
                    </mat-datepicker>
                </mat-form-field>
```

The popup-window is rendered OUTSIDE the App-root actually, like this:

[image]

BTW, the mat-datepicker itself is positioned correct inside the app-root somewhere, but since i cant control the popup it gets positionen waay outside.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Tell me if you need something more, will respond quickly!
Thanks!

Comment: Wrapping the datepicker in a  <div class="mat-app-background basic-container" style="background-color: white"> solved it for me eventually!!

Answer (score 0):

use

```
display="anchored"
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.